# dll error when trying to import a package, but running that same env in the terminal allows to import the package

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv

As the title states PyCharm is giving me a weird error. I have the Conda env activated in my terminal, and I have the interpreter set for PyCharm, but when I try to

```py
import seaborn
```

I get a

```
  File "C:/name/projects/dir/project.py", line 4, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import palettes
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\venvs\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\venvs\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 169, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\venvs\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But when I run

```py
import seaborn
```

in my terminal I don't get this error. Any ideas/explanations?

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the same environment activated in PyCharm and in the Terminal? You can check that with running:
`import sys; print(sys.version)`
Is the output the same in PyCharm and in the Terminal?

Comment: yes exact same output
3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]